# processes consuming data over network

Tags: apt, snap, network-monitoring

Since using a usb modem with a 2GB contract per month, I need to take care of who's consuming data over network.
It turns out that:
1) snapd connects from time to time, is there a way to configure it?
2) even if I said in the graphical interface not to controls system update, aptd is still running quite often. How can I stop this behaviour? I use to run apt-get manually.
Thanks

Comment: Do you actually use snaps? You can safely uninstall snapd if not.

Comment: I have only one snap installed. Anyway, I do not want to uninstall it, just to configure snap not to look for update every how and then. The same thing should be possibile, for example, with apt.